# Catalina download taking forever

Tags: macos, catalina, software-update

I am currently downloading the OS upgrade Catalina for my Macbook Air. I have sufficient space (over 25Gb) on my hard drive. Initially, it shows the download to be quick with ETA ~40mins (till around 1Gb), but then suddenly slips to over days. It is not completely stopped, it is going on, but at snail's pace. My internet is definitely not so slow. What could be the problem?

Is there any method to pause the download and continue after a shutdown or sleep? 3 days is very long and I have already lost the download twice due to power off and accidentally closing the laptop.

Also, the past downloads I have lost, seem to be taking up space - my mac now shows 4Gb less free, after the previous download stopped at 4Gb. Is there any way I can clean them up to reclaim space?

edit - this is continuing to happen. I have presently downloaded 7Gb of 8gGb and it still shows 2 days ETA. Previous downloads that were stalled now account to 12Gb of my space and now it is taking away precious space (128Gb Mac). Even if this update doesn't work, I need to delete the occupied space.

edit 2 - the download is finally over - over 2 days (with download speed being 45mbps since ppl have asked - I think speed wasn't the issue as the initial few Gb was downloaded very fast). The problem is that to install the update I need 10Gb additional space which now I don't have. I would have to delete over 15gb of partially downloaded update files to be able to do this.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm your Internet speed with a tool like http://speedtest.net?  As far as the update goes, it will resume from where it left off.

Comment: Do you have high-speed internet?  What is your internet rate when just a test? Basically same comment as Allan.

Comment: I wouldn't delete anything related to the download until it has completed.

Comment: The download speed is 48mbps according to Ookla speedtest

Comment: I need to now delete the partially downloaded update files. Is there any way I can do this?